# Annotating List of Enums in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, enums, annotations

I have this annotation in hibernat for list of Enums :

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = SomeType.class)
@JoinTable(name = "table_name",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = FK_NAME)
)
@Column(name = "someTypeCd", nullable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<SomeType> someType;
```

And problem is when i call search query execution it return  this :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 11):

As I came here through searching for the solution:

```
@Column
@Enumerated
@ElementCollection(targetClass = MyEnum.class)
private List<MyEnum> values;
```

did the job for me. Thanks for the hint to `@ElementCollection` I were not aware of it.

Your pasted snippped might bring the problem, that you describe your enum value to be of type String with `@Enumerated(EnumType.String)`. I guss this brings in the cast exception. Maybe `EnumType.Ordinal` would be suiting. I am not experienced with that. I am fine by not defining anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change the @Column definition to include the defined enum values, e.g.

```
@Column(name="someTypeCd", nullable = false, columnDefinition="enum('VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3', 'UNDEFINED')")
```